# Changes to git branch

Tags: git

I am working on 'master' branch and checkout a new branch 'addheader' 
I then make changes while on 'addheader' branch
I then checkout 'master' again
Now the changes I made while working on 'addheader' are still visible (sublime editor)

Should this be the case? Should it not revert back to previous version?

Comment: Unless and until you've committed your changes on `addheader` branch, changes will be visible on your `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If the changes you have made in the `addheader` branch could be overwritten by checking out the `master` branch (i.e. if there could have been any merge conflicts had both these branches been merged), then git will notify you to either `commit` or [`stash`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) the changes before checking out. If you do either of these, the modified files will not be visible in the branch that is checked out later.

If the changes will not be overwritten by checking out `master`, git will allow you to checkout without committing or staging the changes. In that case, the changes will be visible as `M` (modified) files when you do a `git status` after checking out the branch.